# Is possible to delete folder var/session in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, session

I have 4.4 GB file in `var/session` folder. The free space is very limited so is possible to delete that folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can clear it safely, but your customers will be loggedout and their carts will be cleared.

If you have a space issue, other than clearing your `var/session` path you could **consider moving to database session handling**.

If you like to move to DB session system:

Open `app/etc/local.xml`:

Change:

```
<session_save>file</session_save>
```

To:

```
<session_save>db</session_save>
```

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively you could run a command like this that will delete files within the session folder older than X Days

```
find var/session/* -mtime +X -exec rm {} \;
```

Change X to the number of days. Then the most recent sessions will be safe and customers currently checking out will be fine.

**Be careful with the location so you do not delete something you don't want to and take backups before doing something like this**

Comment: duplicate question and answer....

Comment: Faster without * as the shell won't call find for each file

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can delete the var/session folder. Once you delete the folders from the var/session folder your all customers who are currently logged in will be loggout and you as a admin also will logout

Basically all current sessions will logout.

Answer (score 1):

go to root path of the site , than you can run this command from terminal `rm -rf var/session/*` but if you do this , if any guest added items to cart will become empty. also you will log out from the backend. even customers have to login again in frontend.